# Textual output appears wrong and contains inexplicable symbols

Tags: matlab, logging, text, output, non-printing-characters

When I run my code the output appears like an error. What can be done about this?

Here's the part of my code that does the printing:

```
if (dtw(Bs(:,4),AY) > 40) && (dtw(Bs(:,4),AY)< 68) 
    SOEvent=1;
    X=['event is', SOEvent,'in duration',(i:i+200)];
    disp(X);
elseif (dtw(As(:,4),AY) > 60 ) && (dtw(Bs(:,4),AY)< 130) 
     SOEvent=2;   
      X=['event is', SOEvent,'in duration',(i:i+200)];
    disp(X);

elseif (dtw(LLchs(:,4),AX) > 105) && (dtw(LLchs(:,4),AX)< 190)
        SOEvent=3;
         X=['event is', SOEvent,'in duration',(i:i+200)];
    disp(X);
elseif (dtw(Rlchs(:,4),AX) > 55) && (dtw(Rlchs(:,4),AX)< 100) 
    SOEvent=4;
     X=['event is', SOEvent,'in duration',(i:i+200)];
    disp(X);

 else 
     disp('no event')

end
```

The output of the code is:

```
event isin durationÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿĀāĂăĄąĆćĈĉĊċČčĎďĐđĒēĔĕĖėĘęĚěĜĝĞğĠġĢģĤĥĦħĨĩĪīĬĭĮįİıĲĳĴĵĶķĸĹĺĻļĽľĿŀŁłŃńŅņŇňŉŊŋŌōŎŏŐőŒœŔŕŖŗŘřŚśŜŝŞşŠšŢţŤťŦŧŨũŪūŬŭŮůŰűŲųŴŵŶŷŸŹźŻżŽžſƀƁƂƃƄƅƆƇƈƉƊƋƌƍƎƏƐƑ
no event
no event
event isin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`num2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html) to convert numbers to strings (or character arrays) so that they can be concatenated and printed using `disp`.

Please make sure you format your code properly when you ask questions, because the cause of the problem (placeholder characters) is only visible when looking at your raw post (i.e. editing).